# SQLSERVER get last record from recordset

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get only last record

```
strConnStr = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;..."
Set cn = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.Open strConnStr
    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT year1 FROM cars WHERE year1 > 1900 ORDER BY year1;" 
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set rs.ActiveConnection = cn
    rs.Open strSQL
    YearList = rs.GetRows()
    rs.MoveLast
    MaxYear = rs.Fields(0)
cn.Close 
set rs = Nothing
set cn = nothing    

response.write MaxYear
```

return nothing, also i tryed `MaxYear = rs(0)`, `MaxYear = rs("Year1")` all return nothing

I do not need to change strSQL !!!

Also i get error on rs.movelast

> Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 error '80040e24'
>
> Rowset does not support fetching backward.

Comment: Have you run the SQL query in the server, what is the result?

Comment: Result is List of distincts Years from 1900 to 2015 sorting from small to hight

Comment: So what is the rs.RecordCount, is it 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the update:

```
Set rs.ActiveConnection = cn
    rs.Open strSQL
    YearList = rs.GetRows()
    MaxYear = YearList(0,UBound(YearList))
cn.Close
```

---

Older answer:

<strike>If you're insistent on not changing the SQL (and so forcing the server to do more work on data that you're just going to throw away), then you just need to move through the whole recordset:</strike>

```
rs.Open strSQL
while Not rs.EOF
  YearArr = rs.Fields(0)
  rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: I want to get only max value not want to iterate throught all recordset

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - then I really don't understand. You don't want to change the SQL, which is the logical thing to do. So I've given you an answer where you don't have to change the SQL, and that's still not what you want.

Comment: Yes as i want to get only one value which is with my strSql is last and also is max

Comment: If you only want one row then just **change** the SQL, as the other answers have told you to.

Comment: Hmmm, this strSql used to get other things also not only to get this value, as i need get distinct years list too which i get with `YearList = rs.GetRows()` and i want to get one value from this recordset! do not want to create million connections for every purpose

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - if you're already using `GetRows` then just use `UBound` on the array to find the last index and get the data from the array.

Comment: Please fix answer from `YearList(UBound(YearList),0)` to `YearList(0,UBound(YearList,2))` as GetRows return twodimensional array

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - done, I've not got runnable code in front of me and I've not been writing VBA for years, so errors are bound to creep in.

Comment: It is not vba )) its Vbscript

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TOP keyword to get the latest record like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 year1 FROM cars WHERE year1 > 1900 
group by year1 
ORDER BY year1 desc;
```

Comment: but i need distinct list of year too

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin be clear, you want sorted list or last record ?

Comment: i want last record from sorted list

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin:- Updated my answer. Also when you are using the GROUP BY you dont have to use the DISTINCT.

Comment: Problem not in strSQL problem is how to get this value to variable from recordset

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TOP keyword to get the latest record desc like this

```
SELECT TOP 1 year1 FROM cars WHERE year1 > 1900 
group by year1 
ORDER BY year1 Desc;
```